# What is the fastest way for a new programmer to learn ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to learn ASP.net 3.5 effectively, but I have no fluent knowledge of any other languages.

Now the scenario is that span of time is very less and in short time I have to be upgraded with ASP.net skills.

So I am interested in fast and effective way to learn ASP.net 3.5.

I have to start from scratch.

Please..please........I want solution as soon as possible.........

And please mention good books and online material.

Thanks.Waiting for reply.

Comment: No prior programming knowledge whatsoever?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in WebForms, or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Do you have a project in mind for which you plan to use ASP.NET? If you can provide more information about what you need to do then people will be able to offer more detailed assistance.

Answer (score 9):

First thing is to drop statements like: `"I want solution as soon as possible"`. To learn something new takes time and you'll need to cool down before getting results.

I strongly recommend you to build something for yourself. This way you can deal with new requirements and schedule pressure. During this process, you'll need to see how other people do same thing, and then to download some sample codes.

**EDIT**: I think you should start doing that every application does: trying to access a database and changing data. This path will lead you to know more about Entity Data Model and LINQ. So you can go to code your front-end. You can take a look at [NerdDinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/) website for MVC samples.

Comment: If he wants to learn ASP.Net and has no prior knowledge, MVC may seem mystical. MVC has a lot of "defaults" and "magical" behaviors which can be hard to grasp for someone new to the Microsoft stack. Then again I may completely be off on this one because to understand viewstate and postback with the page life-cycle can also be hard to grasp...

Comment: as I agree with your point (asp.net its easier than mvc) depends on his background and his professional target.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of good tutorials at [asp.net/learn](http://asp.net/learn).

If you're interested in ASP.NET MVC (Microsoft's latest web UI framework) then there's a good set of tutorials at [asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_Overview](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_Overview)

It might be worth mentioning that you have a choice of programming languages to use; VB.NET or C#. If you are new to programming then you might want to spend some time getting comfortable with one of these initially, as well as familiarising yourself with the underlying .NET Framework.

If you can provide more details about what you need to achieve, as well as your programming background then people will be able to provide advice that is more specific to your situation.

Comment: I'd like to mention that you are not limited to VB.Net or C#, setting the compile settings will enable you to use other languages as well.

Comment: @Alexandre: True, but VB.NET and C# are the dominant two

Answer (score 5):

It takes about [ten years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html), as does learning anything worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn a new set of development skills is total immersion in a project. Build your own website and follow along with a book or two, make some mistakes and fix them, and in general endure all the rough-and-tumble that development involves. Along the way, make sure you're investing good time in writing solid unit tests, so that you understand what they're for and why you should be writing them.

If you've never programmed before, this is going to be rather challenging as a first project. ASP.NET MVC requires understanding, if not fluency, of many different pieces of web development. But dedication, persistence, and curiosity will be enough to win out here.

Answer (score 1):

I think reading a good book while implementing some basic website will be your best approach.

My personal favorite, with good inside examples and good practices is [Pro ASP.NET MVC](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430210079)

Answer (score 0):

Get a book like [ASP.NET 2.0 Website Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764584642) from Wrox Press and work your way through it from beginning to end. Immerse yourself this this project, follow all the steps and understand every step along the way.

Microsoft offers 2 distinct Web development systems - "Classic" ASP.NET WebForms, and MVC. In my opinion MVC is more "pure" to the web philosophy but is trickier to learn, the controls aren't as rich and varied, and there are fewer resources to help you. WebForms have been around much longer, there are thousands of books and helpful sites, and there are probably more job opportunities.

Good luck. If you're smart and work really hard, you should have no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Saying you want to learn ASP.NET from scratch is like saying you want to learn to build a house.  You can get a book that shows you how to saw lumber or nail boards together -- but there's a lot more to building a house than any book can effectively communicate.

Learning a specific control or a narrow skill can be done in a few days, but really learning ASP.NET from beginning to end is a multi-year project -- particularly if you have to learn the language too.  Learning C# well could take a year by itself.

Experience is the best teacher. If you can get a mentor of some kind involved, that's even better (just like how carpenters need to apprentice for some time before they're ready to build a house by themselves).

Answer (score 0):

In all seriousness, start with at least 3 years at university doing a computer science/engineering course of some description.

There **is no** fast and "effective" way of learning to program *and* being any good at it. There's a lot, lot more to software development than just the code as anyone who has been doing it for any length of time (and cares about their craft) will attest to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define what exactly do you mean by "learn effectively"?  Do you mean that you want to be able to write code like Jon Skeet at the end?  Or do you mean that you should be able to handle the job of a junior developer?  There is a lot of room between those, to say nothing of you not stating how you learn best:  Do you absorb information best from reading, seeing, doing, or some other format of data?  How good are your Google skills?  How well do you know of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) and the massive amount of information contained within?

[Scott Gutherie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) may not be a bad idea for another resource to consider.  Another point to consider is however fast you want to learn 3.5, there will soon be a 4.0 that may be out sometime this year as part of Visual Studio 2010.